# Absolute ratios

Tags: absolute-value

I'm curious about the following idea:

suppose we have two values $P$ and $Q$, and the magnitude of the ratio $\frac{P}{Q}$ is between $0$ and $\infty$. If $P$ is smaller, then it's between $0$ and $1$.  If $Q$ is smaller, it's between $1$ and $\infty$ (but the ratio $\frac{P}{Q}$ is between $0$ and $1$).

Is there a way to denote the "absolute ratio" (my term) that is always the ratio that is between $0$ and $1$ (either $\frac{P}{Q}$ or $\frac{Q}{P}$)?

As an example, the $\operatorname{absratio}(10,1) = \operatorname{absratio}(1,10) = 0.1.$

Comment: This function should definitely have a name, and the fact that I found this question looking for "absolute ratio" is already a point to its favor

Comment: It doesn't give the same numerical results, but I saw $r=\frac{16pq}{\left(2p+2q\right)^{2}}$ [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4840568/1156) as [an interesting alternative](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zojtwnj9zx) to $r=\min\left(\frac{p}{q},\frac{q}{p}\right)$

Answer (score 7):

Because we're not supposed to start sentences with mathematical symbols, I'm presenting the answer this way: $$\displaystyle \min \biggl(\left\{\frac{P}{Q} ,\frac{Q}{P}\right\}\biggr).$$

Comment: haha! just like (abs n: -n if n < 0 else n)...i prefer |n|

Comment: @user62213 Exactly, nice point. And by the way, you can introduce the notation you suggested in your question if you wish, you just need to explain what it is.

Answer (score 4):

I frequently find myself using this function. The prettiest statement, to my taste, is: $$absratio(A,B) = exp\{{|log(A)-log(B)|\}}$$

Comment: You must 1/x this to get the value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of candidates:
$$
\frac12\left(\frac PQ+\frac QP-\left|\frac PQ-\frac QP\right|\right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{|P+Q|-|P-Q|}{|P+Q|+|P-Q|}
$$

Comment: I like the latter.